# How to check if a remote image meets certain specifications

Tags: java, jsp

I'm doing some coding in JSP/Java (without any framework, or other strange things) and I get stuck trying to find a way to check if a remote image (by URL) meets some specifications, like some defined height and width.

Is there a way to do this in JSP/Java? It's quite easy in PHP, but I can't find the way here ...

Thanks for your time.
Best regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way if probably to use the [ImageIO](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) class to create a BufferedImage, though it isn't the only mechanism in the standard library.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    URL imageUrl = new URL("http://www.google.com/intl/en_ALL/images/logo.gif");
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(imageUrl);
    System.out.println("Width="+image.getWidth());
    System.out.println("Height="+image.getHeight());
}
```